# DBT set column metadata using macros

Tags: dbt

I'm trying to set my column metadata in sql using macros instead of in yml, but can't figure out if this is possible.

I'm currently successfully setting policy_tags in the yml, eg test.yml:

```
version: 2

models:
- name: test
  columns:
    - name: a
      policy_tags: ["MY_TAG"]
```

However, I'd like to do the same thing in SQL, with something like:

```
{# FAKE CODE, DOESN'T WORK %#}
{{ config.set('columns', [{ name: "a", policy_tags: ["MY_TAG"] }]) }}
```

I'm dynamically generating a variable number of columns in the sql using macros, so this would let me also dynamically tag all those columns. Any suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Turned out I was able to do this in a post_hook by calling persist_docs directly:

```
# my_model.sql
{{ config({'post-hook': "{{ write_policy_tags() }}"}) }}

## write_policy_tags.sql
{% macro write_policy_tags() %}
  {% set columns = {
    "col1": { "policy_tags": ["{{ col1tag }}"] },
    "col2": { "policy_tags": ["{{ col2tag }}"] }
  } %}
  {% do persist_docs(this, { "columns": columns }) %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Within the macro, I was then able to call `run_query` and use the results to dynamically generate the `columns` variable to pass to `persist_docs`, which achieved my original goal of dynamic policy_tags.